# Why does DataPoint.AxesLabel not appear on the chart? (MS Chart)

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm adding my points to the chart like this:

```
var point = new DataPoint(xValue.TimeStamp.Ticks, yValue);
point.AxisLabel = "someString";
series.Points.Add(point);
```

But the AxisLabel doesn't appear on my chart.
When I'm using this code the labels appear but as double and not as i want:

```
series.Points.AddXY(xValue.TimeStamp.Ticks, yValue);
```

My AxisValueTyp is set to double.

Is there something i miss? Do I have to set something within the labelsettings of the chartArea X Axis?

Answer (score 0):

Ticks are  of type `long`. If you are using Ticks for your X-Axis you can use the

```
series.Points.AddXY(xValue.TimeStamp.Ticks, yValue);
```

format to add the data points.

You didn't say what format you want. To set the format from the standard axis format `double` to a more suitable number format use e.g.

```
yourChartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "###,###,###,##0";
```

for the X-Axis of yourChartArea.